# iOS data tables and optimal storage

Tags: ios, datastore

I am building an iOS application that will randomly generate sentences (think Mad Libs) where the data used for generation is in multiple tables.  This will be used to generate scenarios for training lifeguards.  Each table contains an item name, the words that will be used when selected, and different values that determine what can go togeather.
[image: Location Table]
[image: Pre-event table]
Using two of the 10 tables shown above, the application may pick a location of Deep Water.  Then it needs to pick an appropriate activity for in the water, such as Breath holding, but not Running.

I have been looking at Core Data for storage but that seems to be more for data that is changing often by the user and users would never change the data stored.  I do want to be able to update the tables myself fairly easily.  What would be the optimal solution to do this?  The ways I think of are:

- Some kind of SQL DB, though my tables again aren't changing and
  aren't relationshipable.
- 2-D arrays written into the source code. Not pretty to work with or read, but my knowledge of regex makes converting from TSV to array fairly easy.
- TSV files attached to the project.  Better organization itself but take some research on how to access.
- Some other method Apple has that I do not know about.